# Getting a random simple path between two nodes in a graph

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

Given the start node and goal node in a graph, I want to find **one** simple path between these two nodes. I do not want the shortest path, but need any random simple path.
I tried using `all_simple_paths` from networkx, but this module seems to calculate all the simple paths before returning anything. This takes a long time to run.
Is there a way to find just one simple path?

Also, I would ideally like to make sure this path does not cross any "obstacles". These obstacles are a predefined set of nodes from the same graph. Is there a way to add in this constraint?

PS: I don't necessarily need to use networkx. The code I am writing is in Python.

Answer (score 1):

You could treat this as a min cost network flow problem where your start node wants to send a unit of flow (demand = -1) to your goal node (demand = 1). You can set the edge capacities to 1 and you can set all the edge weights to 0 except for those around "obstacle" nodes. For those obstacle nodes you can set all the edges either coming into or going out of them to have a weight of 1. The algorithm will try to find any arbitrary path using only edges with weight 0, but will use weight 1 edges if no path exists with only weight 0 edges.

See the `nx.min_cost_flow` function. This function requires you to make your graph a directed graph `nx.DiGraph` if it's not already.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem by using the RRT algorithm. It gives a random path between the source and destination nodes and also avoids obstacles.